# Error "opencart Modification requires a unique ID code" when uploading ocmod.xml file

Tags: opencart2.3, ocmod

I'm going through opencart tutorial and when I try to upload my modification I get the following error: `"Modification requires a unique ID code!"`. The modification has the `<code>` tag. I'm using opencart  2.3.0.2.

The code of the modification:

```
<modification>  
<name>Add Header Notification in the catalog and admin pages</name> 
<version>1.0</version>                
<link>http://isenselabs.com</link>                
<author>iSenseLabs</author>                                                                 
<code>new_u_name</code>
<file path=”admin/view/template/common/header.tpl”>   
    <operation>        
        <search>      
            <![CDATA[<header id=”header” class=”navbar navbar-static-top”>]]>       
        </search>       
        <add position=”replace”>            
            <![CDATA[                
                <div id=”HeaderNotification” style=” background-color: #F54661; z-index- :99999;font-size:22px;
                text-align:center; color:#fff; position:fixed;width:100%;height: 40px- ;line-height:40px;top:0px;”>
                Header Notification in Your Admin Panel</div><header id=”header” class=”navbar navbar-static-top” style=”margin-top:40px;”>           
                ]]>        
        </add>     
    </operation> 
</file>
<file path=”catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl”>    
    <operation>        
        <search>
            <![CDATA[</head>]]>        
        </search>        
        <add  position=”after”>            
            <![CDATA[                
            <div id=”HeaderNotification” style=” background-color: #F54661; z-index:99999;font-size:22px;
            text-align:center; color:#fff; position:fixed;width:100%;height: 40px;line-height:40px;top:0px;”>Header 
            Notification in Your Store</div><header id=”header” class=”navbar navbar-static-top” style=”margin-top:40px;”>
            ]]> 
        </add>     
    </operation> 
</file>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this, the example was from the book 'Opencart tips and tricks' and when you copy-paste the code you get wrong double quotes around  `”after”`. Retyping the quotes fixes the problem.

Comment: In my case the issue was wrong xml format. I forgot to add  </file>